# Jqplot, split an dynamic diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

i have an diagram that have 12 values and i want to split it in 3 diagram that have 4 values each diagram. So i can have 4 diagrams. The list of arrays is dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10,2, 6, 7, 10,2, 6, 7, 10];
        var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 2,7, 5, 3, 2,7, 5, 3, 2];
        var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8,14, 9, 3, 8,14, 9, 3, 8];
       var s4 = [15, 8, 2, 10,15, 8, 2, 10,15, 8, 2, 10,];

        plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3, s4], {
            stackSeries: true,
            captureRightClick: true,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    highlightMouseDown: true   
                },
                pointLabels: {show: true}
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'outside'
            }      
        });
     
        $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataRightClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        ); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.enhancedPieLegendRenderer.min.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

<div  id="chart3"></div>
```

And the question is how can i do this ? i have an array that looks like:

```
 array(0 => array(0 => array(0 => 2,1 => 6,2 => 7,3 => 10)),//this will be the first diagram
       1 => array(0 => array(0 => 7,1 => 5,2 => 3,3 => 2)),// this the second       
       2 => array(0 => array(0 => 14,1 => 9,2 => 3,3 => 14)),//this the third
       3 => array(0 => array(0 => 15,1 => 8,2 => 2,3 => 10))//this the fourth
       );
```

The list is dynamic. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: so this php array is presented on your jquery code page??

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over your array and create a chart based on each sub-array data like below:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.enhancedPieLegendRenderer.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

<?php
$array = array(
            0 => array(
                    0 => array(
                        2, 6, 7, 10,2, 6, 7, 10,2, 6, 7, 10
                )
            ),
            1 => array(
                    0 => array(
                        7, 5, 3, 2,7, 5, 3, 2,7, 5, 3, 22
                )
            ),
            2 => array(
                    0 => array(
                        14, 9, 3, 8,14, 9, 3, 8,14, 9, 3, 8
                )
            ),3 => array(
                    0 => array(
                        15, 8, 2, 10,15, 8, 2, 10,15, 8, 2, 10,
                    )
            ),4 => array(
                    0 => array(
                        12, 18, 2, 0,1, 8, 2, 7,6, 8, 2, 21,
                    )
            )
       );


foreach($array as $key=> $arr){?>
<div  id="chart<?php echo $key;?>"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        plot3 = $.jqplot('chart<?php echo $key;?>', <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>, {
            stackSeries: true,
            captureRightClick: true,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    highlightMouseDown: true   
                },
                pointLabels: {show: true}
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'outside'
            }      
        });

        $('#chart<?php echo $key;?>').bind('jqplotDataRightClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        ); 
    });

</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: as i said i have an dynamic list whats means that i can have sometime an array with 3 or with 2 , 1 ... and the question was how can i make the diagram in jquery, like foreach array if isset ...

Comment: is but it doesn't mean that diagram must to have only 4, the array list is dynamic i can have also 5 or 6 list and i want foreach list a diagram .